# How to send arrayList in RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I'm working on a Java project that needs to deliver and receive message in RabbitMQ.

My project is based on an Object Arraylist that contains more than 1000 rows. Is it possible to pass this list in one time and receive it in the same way?

Comment: That might be a design issue you are facing here. Usually message should be very small to not slow down your message broker with handling large amounts of data. What you can do if you have to "pass large data along" is to save it somewhere else (like a database or shared storage) and then send the required information to find it again in the message (database id, path in a storage).

What kind of data is contained in your list? I guess some more information might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

The message payload is an "[opaque byte array](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#messages)", as the rabbitmq main website indicates.
So nothing stops you from providing a serialized array as the message payload.

Although as stated by @DrunkenPope it's more common to have small messages, in our environment we do send full json payloads in the messages, sometimes going up to 100MB. It does have a performance impact, but it's completely feasible.

Still, indeed you should review your use case to figure out what makes the most sense, as a single message with the array in the payload means that you will have a single consumer handling the 1000 rows, while if you generate a separate message for each row, you can easily have multiple consumers share the processing.

If you're still in doubt about which approach to consider, please provide more details as to what you are trying to achieve, the community will surely be happy to chime in on what is likely the better option for your use case.